# Is there a list of exception codes and error messages?

Tags: apex

Does Salesforce have a list of all the exceptions published somewhere on the web?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Somewhat and no. Most are published by the API that uses them. If you want Apex exceptions, you can find them in the [Apex Code Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm). Others (like SOAP and REST), you'll find in the API documents for the particular API linked from the [Developer Documentation page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs). There are some, that simply aren't documented and you'll typically receive a message that will appear along side of them to contact Salesforce Support for more information.

Answer (score 7):

You could also generate the API file for your org to find all error/status codes there exist.

```
<simpleType name="StatusCode">
    <restriction base="xsd:string">
        <enumeration value="ALL_OR_NONE_OPERATION_ROLLED_BACK"/>
        <enumeration value="ALREADY_IN_PROCESS"/>
        <enumeration value="APEX_DATA_ACCESS_RESTRICTION"/>
        <enumeration value="ASSIGNEE_TYPE_REQUIRED"/>
        <enumeration value="AURA_COMPILE_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="BAD_CUSTOM_ENTITY_PARENT_DOMAIN"/>
        <enumeration value="BCC_NOT_ALLOWED_IF_BCC_COMPLIANCE_ENABLED"/>
        <enumeration value="CANNOT_CASCADE_PRODUCT_ACTIVE"/>
        <enumeration value="CANNOT_CHANGE_FIELD_TYPE_OF_APEX_REFERENCED_FIELD"/>
        <enumeration value="CANNOT_CHANGE_FIELD_TYPE_OF_REFERENCED_FIELD"/>
        <enumeration value="CANNOT_CREATE_ANOTHER_MANAGED_PACKAGE"/>
        <enumeration value="CANNOT_DEACTIVATE_DIVISION"/>
        <enumeration value="CANNOT_DELETE_GLOBAL_ACTION_LIST"/>
        <enumeration value="CANNOT_DELETE_LAST_DATED_CONVERSION_RATE"/>
        <enumeration value="CANNOT_DELETE_MANAGED_OBJECT"/>
        <enumeration value="CANNOT_DISABLE_LAST_ADMIN"/>
        <enumeration value="CANNOT_ENABLE_IP_RESTRICT_REQUESTS"/>
        <enumeration value="CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER"/>
        <enumeration value="CANNOT_FREEZE_SELF"/>
        <enumeration value="CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY"/>
        <enumeration value="CANNOT_MODIFY_MANAGED_OBJECT"/>
        <enumeration value="CANNOT_PASSWORD_LOCKOUT"/>
        <enumeration value="CANNOT_POST_TO_ARCHIVED_GROUP"/>
        <enumeration value="CANNOT_RENAME_APEX_REFERENCED_FIELD"/>
        <enumeration value="CANNOT_RENAME_APEX_REFERENCED_OBJECT"/>
        <enumeration value="CANNOT_RENAME_REFERENCED_FIELD"/>
        <enumeration value="CANNOT_RENAME_REFERENCED_OBJECT"/>
        <enumeration value="CANNOT_REPARENT_RECORD"/>
        <enumeration value="CANNOT_UPDATE_CONVERTED_LEAD"/>
        <enumeration value="CANT_DISABLE_CORP_CURRENCY"/>
        <enumeration value="CANT_UNSET_CORP_CURRENCY"/>
        <enumeration value="CHILD_SHARE_FAILS_PARENT"/>
        <enumeration value="CIRCULAR_DEPENDENCY"/>
        <enumeration value="CLEAN_SERVICE_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="COLLISION_DETECTED"/>
        <enumeration value="COMMERCIAL_CONTROL_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="COMMUNITY_NOT_ACCESSIBLE"/>
        <enumeration value="CONFLICTING_ENVIRONMENT_HUB_MEMBER"/>
        <enumeration value="CONFLICTING_SSO_USER_MAPPING"/>
        <enumeration value="CUSTOM_APEX_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="CUSTOM_CLOB_FIELD_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="CUSTOM_ENTITY_OR_FIELD_LIMIT"/>
        <enumeration value="CUSTOM_FIELD_INDEX_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="CUSTOM_INDEX_EXISTS"/>
        <enumeration value="CUSTOM_LINK_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="CUSTOM_METADATA_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="CUSTOM_METADATA_REL_FIELD_MANAGEABILITY"/>
        <enumeration value="CUSTOM_SETTINGS_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="CUSTOM_TAB_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="DATAASSESSMENT_CONFIG_ASSESSMENT_IN_PROGRESS_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="DATAASSESSMENT_CONFIG_SERVICE_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="DATACLOUDADDRESS_NO_RECORDS_FOUND"/>
        <enumeration value="DATACLOUDADDRESS_PROCESSING_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="DATACLOUDADDRESS_SERVER_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="DELETE_FAILED"/>
        <enumeration value="DELETE_NOT_ALLOWED"/>
        <enumeration value="DELETE_OPERATION_TOO_LARGE"/>
        <enumeration value="DELETE_REQUIRED_ON_CASCADE"/>
        <enumeration value="DEPENDENCY_EXISTS"/>
        <enumeration value="DUPLICATES_DETECTED"/>
        <enumeration value="DUPLICATE_CASE_SOLUTION"/>
        <enumeration value="DUPLICATE_COMM_NICKNAME"/>
        <enumeration value="DUPLICATE_CUSTOM_ENTITY_DEFINITION"/>
        <enumeration value="DUPLICATE_CUSTOM_TAB_MOTIF"/>
        <enumeration value="DUPLICATE_DEVELOPER_NAME"/>
        <enumeration value="DUPLICATE_EXTERNAL_ID"/>
        <enumeration value="DUPLICATE_MASTER_LABEL"/>
        <enumeration value="DUPLICATE_SENDER_DISPLAY_NAME"/>
        <enumeration value="DUPLICATE_USERNAME"/>
        <enumeration value="DUPLICATE_VALUE"/>
        <enumeration value="EMAIL_ADDRESS_BOUNCED"/>
        <enumeration value="EMAIL_EXTERNAL_TRANSPORT_CONNECTION_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="EMAIL_EXTERNAL_TRANSPORT_PERMISSION_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="EMAIL_EXTERNAL_TRANSPORT_TOKEN_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="EMAIL_EXTERNAL_TRANSPORT_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="EMAIL_EXTERNAL_TRANSPORT_UNKNOWN_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="EMAIL_NOT_PROCESSED_DUE_TO_PRIOR_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="EMAIL_OPTED_OUT"/>
        <enumeration value="EMAIL_TEMPLATE_FORMULA_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="EMAIL_TEMPLATE_MERGEFIELD_ACCESS_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="EMAIL_TEMPLATE_MERGEFIELD_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="EMAIL_TEMPLATE_MERGEFIELD_VALUE_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="EMAIL_TEMPLATE_PROCESSING_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="EMPTY_SCONTROL_FILE_NAME"/>
        <enumeration value="ENHANCED_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_COMPILATION_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="ENTITY_FAILED_IFLASTMODIFIED_ON_UPDATE"/>
        <enumeration value="ENTITY_IS_ARCHIVED"/>
        <enumeration value="ENTITY_IS_DELETED"/>
        <enumeration value="ENTITY_IS_LOCKED"/>
        <enumeration value="ENTITY_SAVE_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="ENTITY_SAVE_VALIDATION_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="ENVIRONMENT_HUB_MEMBERSHIP_CONFLICT"/>
        <enumeration value="ENVIRONMENT_HUB_MEMBERSHIP_ERROR_JOINING_HUB"/>
        <enumeration value="ENVIRONMENT_HUB_MEMBERSHIP_USER_ALREADY_IN_HUB"/>
        <enumeration value="ENVIRONMENT_HUB_MEMBERSHIP_USER_NOT_ORG_ADMIN"/>
        <enumeration value="ERROR_IN_MAILER"/>
        <enumeration value="EXCHANGE_WEB_SERVICES_URL_INVALID"/>
        <enumeration value="FAILED_ACTIVATION"/>
        <enumeration value="FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION"/>
        <enumeration value="FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION"/>
        <enumeration value="FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION"/>
        <enumeration value="FIELD_KEYWORD_LIST_MATCH_LIMIT"/>
        <enumeration value="FIELD_MAPPING_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="FIELD_MODERATION_RULE_BLOCK"/>
        <enumeration value="FIELD_NOT_UPDATABLE"/>
        <enumeration value="FILE_EXTENSION_NOT_ALLOWED"/>
        <enumeration value="FILE_SIZE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="FILTERED_LOOKUP_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="FIND_DUPLICATES_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="FLOW_EXCEPTION"/>
        <enumeration value="FUNCTIONALITY_NOT_ENABLED"/>
        <enumeration value="HAS_PUBLIC_REFERENCES"/>
        <enumeration value="HTML_FILE_UPLOAD_NOT_ALLOWED"/>
        <enumeration value="IMAGE_TOO_LARGE"/>
        <enumeration value="INACTIVE_OWNER_OR_USER"/>
        <enumeration value="INACTIVE_RULE_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="INSERT_UPDATE_DELETE_NOT_ALLOWED_DURING_MAINTENANCE"/>
        <enumeration value="INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY"/>
        <enumeration value="INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY"/>
        <enumeration value="INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_TO_INSIGHTSEXTERNALDATA"/>
        <enumeration value="INSUFFICIENT_CREDITS"/>
        <enumeration value="INTERNAL_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_ACCESS_LEVEL"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_ACCESS_TOKEN"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_API_INPUT"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_ARGUMENT_TYPE"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_ASSIGNEE_TYPE"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_ASSIGNMENT_RULE"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_BATCH_OPERATION"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_CONTENT_TYPE"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_CREDIT_CARD_INFO"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_TYPE_FOR_FIELD"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_CURRENCY_CONV_RATE"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_CURRENCY_CORP_RATE"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_CURRENCY_ISO"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_DATASET_REFERENCE_INPUT"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_DATA_CATEGORY_GROUP_REFERENCE"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_DATA_URI"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_EMPTY_KEY_OWNER"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_ENTITY_FOR_MATCH_ENGINE_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_ENTITY_FOR_MATCH_OPERATION_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_ENTITY_FOR_UPSERT"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_ENVIRONMENT_HUB_MEMBER"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_EVENT_DELIVERY"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_EVENT_INPUT"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_EVENT_SUBSCRIPTION"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_EXTENSION_ID"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_FIELD"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_FIELD_WHEN_USING_TEMPLATE"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_FILTER_ACTION"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_GOOGLE_DOCS_URL"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_ID_FIELD"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_INET_ADDRESS"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_INPUT"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_KEY_FIELD_INPUT"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_LINEITEM_CLONE_STATE"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_MARKUP"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_MASTER_OR_TRANSLATED_SOLUTION"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_MESSAGE_ID_REFERENCE"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_NAMESPACE_PREFIX"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_OAUTH_URL"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_OPERATION"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_OPERATOR"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_OWNER"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_PACKAGE_LICENSE"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_PACKAGE_VERSION"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_PARTNER_NETWORK_STATUS"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_PAYLOAD_VERSION"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_PERSON_ACCOUNT_OPERATION"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_PROVIDER_TYPE"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_QUERY_LOCATOR"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_READ_ONLY_USER_DML"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_REFRESH_TOKEN"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_RUNTIME_VALUE"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_SAVE_AS_ACTIVITY_FLAG"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_SESSION_ID"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_SETUP_OWNER"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_SIGNUP_COUNTRY"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_SIGNUP_OPTION"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_SITE_DELETE_EXCEPTION"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_SITE_FILE_IMPORTED_EXCEPTION"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_SITE_FILE_TYPE_EXCEPTION"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_STATUS"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_SUBDOMAIN"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_TEXT_REPRESENTATION"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_TYPE"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_TYPE_FOR_OPERATION"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_TYPE_ON_FIELD_IN_RECORD"/>
        <enumeration value="INVALID_USERID"/>
        <enumeration value="IP_RANGE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="ITEM_NOT_FOUND"/>
        <enumeration value="JIGSAW_IMPORT_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="LICENSE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="LIGHT_PORTAL_USER_EXCEPTION"/>
        <enumeration value="LIMIT_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="MALFORMED_ID"/>
        <enumeration value="MANAGER_NOT_DEFINED"/>
        <enumeration value="MASSMAIL_RETRY_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="MASS_MAIL_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="MATCH_DEFINITION_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="MATCH_OPERATION_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="MATCH_OPERATION_INVALID_ENGINE_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="MATCH_OPERATION_INVALID_RULE_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="MATCH_OPERATION_MISSING_ENGINE_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="MATCH_OPERATION_MISSING_OBJECT_TYPE_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="MATCH_OPERATION_MISSING_OPTIONS_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="MATCH_OPERATION_MISSING_RULE_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="MATCH_OPERATION_UNKNOWN_RULE_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="MATCH_OPERATION_UNSUPPORTED_VERSION_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="MATCH_PRECONDITION_FAILED"/>
        <enumeration value="MATCH_RUNTIME_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="MATCH_SERVICE_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="MATCH_SERVICE_TIMED_OUT"/>
        <enumeration value="MATCH_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="MAXIMUM_CCEMAILS_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="MAXIMUM_DASHBOARD_COMPONENTS_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="MAXIMUM_HIERARCHY_CHILDREN_REACHED"/>
        <enumeration value="MAXIMUM_HIERARCHY_LEVELS_REACHED"/>
        <enumeration value="MAXIMUM_HIERARCHY_TREE_SIZE_REACHED"/>
        <enumeration value="MAXIMUM_SIZE_OF_ATTACHMENT"/>
        <enumeration value="MAXIMUM_SIZE_OF_DOCUMENT"/>
        <enumeration value="MAX_ACTIONS_PER_RULE_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="MAX_ACTIVE_RULES_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="MAX_APPROVAL_STEPS_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="MAX_DEPTH_IN_FLOW_EXECUTION"/>
        <enumeration value="MAX_FORMULAS_PER_RULE_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="MAX_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="MAX_RULES_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="MAX_RULE_ENTRIES_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="MAX_TASK_DESCRIPTION_EXCEEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="MAX_TM_RULES_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="MAX_TM_RULE_ITEMS_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="MAX_TRIGGERS_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="MERGE_FAILED"/>
        <enumeration value="METADATA_FIELD_UPDATE_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="MISSING_ARGUMENT"/>
        <enumeration value="MISSING_RECORD"/>
        <enumeration value="MIXED_DML_OPERATION"/>
        <enumeration value="NONUNIQUE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS"/>
        <enumeration value="NO_ACCESS_TOKEN"/>
        <enumeration value="NO_ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_REFRESH"/>
        <enumeration value="NO_APPLICABLE_PROCESS"/>
        <enumeration value="NO_ATTACHMENT_PERMISSION"/>
        <enumeration value="NO_AUTH_PROVIDER"/>
        <enumeration value="NO_INACTIVE_DIVISION_MEMBERS"/>
        <enumeration value="NO_MASS_MAIL_PERMISSION"/>
        <enumeration value="NO_PARTNER_PERMISSION"/>
        <enumeration value="NO_REFRESH_TOKEN"/>
        <enumeration value="NO_SUCH_USER_EXISTS"/>
        <enumeration value="NO_TOKEN_ENDPOINT"/>
        <enumeration value="NUMBER_OUTSIDE_VALID_RANGE"/>
        <enumeration value="NUM_HISTORY_FIELDS_BY_SOBJECT_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="OPTED_OUT_OF_MASS_MAIL"/>
        <enumeration value="OP_WITH_INVALID_USER_TYPE_EXCEPTION"/>
        <enumeration value="ORCHESTRATION_INVALID"/>
        <enumeration value="PACKAGE_LICENSE_REQUIRED"/>
        <enumeration value="PACKAGING_API_INSTALL_FAILED"/>
        <enumeration value="PACKAGING_API_UNINSTALL_FAILED"/>
        <enumeration value="PALI_INVALID_ACTION_ID"/>
        <enumeration value="PALI_INVALID_ACTION_NAME"/>
        <enumeration value="PALI_INVALID_ACTION_TYPE"/>
        <enumeration value="PAL_INVALID_ASSISTANT_RECOMMENDATION_TYPE_ID"/>
        <enumeration value="PAL_INVALID_ENTITY_ID"/>
        <enumeration value="PAL_INVALID_FLEXIPAGE_ID"/>
        <enumeration value="PAL_INVALID_LAYOUT_ID"/>
        <enumeration value="PAL_INVALID_PARAMETERS"/>
        <enumeration value="PAYLOAD_SIZE_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="PA_API_EXCEPTION"/>
        <enumeration value="PA_AXIS_FAULT"/>
        <enumeration value="PA_INVALID_ID_EXCEPTION"/>
        <enumeration value="PA_NO_ACCESS_EXCEPTION"/>
        <enumeration value="PA_NO_DATA_FOUND_EXCEPTION"/>
        <enumeration value="PA_URI_SYNTAX_EXCEPTION"/>
        <enumeration value="PA_VISIBLE_ACTIONS_FILTER_ORDERING_EXCEPTION"/>
        <enumeration value="PORTAL_NO_ACCESS"/>
        <enumeration value="PORTAL_USER_ALREADY_EXISTS_FOR_CONTACT"/>
        <enumeration value="PORTAL_USER_CREATION_RESTRICTED_WITH_ENCRYPTION"/>
        <enumeration value="PRIVATE_CONTACT_ON_ASSET"/>
        <enumeration value="PROCESSING_HALTED"/>
        <enumeration value="QA_INVALID_CREATE_FEED_ITEM"/>
        <enumeration value="QA_INVALID_SUCCESS_MESSAGE"/>
        <enumeration value="QUERY_TIMEOUT"/>
        <enumeration value="QUICK_ACTION_LIST_ITEM_NOT_ALLOWED"/>
        <enumeration value="QUICK_ACTION_LIST_NOT_ALLOWED"/>
        <enumeration value="RECORD_IN_USE_BY_WORKFLOW"/>
        <enumeration value="REL_FIELD_BAD_ACCESSIBILITY"/>
        <enumeration value="REPUTATION_MINIMUM_NUMBER_NOT_REACHED"/>
        <enumeration value="REQUEST_RUNNING_TOO_LONG"/>
        <enumeration value="REQUIRED_FEATURE_MISSING"/>
        <enumeration value="REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING"/>
        <enumeration value="RETRIEVE_EXCHANGE_ATTACHMENT_FAILED"/>
        <enumeration value="RETRIEVE_EXCHANGE_EMAIL_FAILED"/>
        <enumeration value="RETRIEVE_EXCHANGE_EVENT_FAILED"/>
        <enumeration value="RETRIEVE_GOOGLE_EMAIL_FAILED"/>
        <enumeration value="RETRIEVE_GOOGLE_EVENT_FAILED"/>
        <enumeration value="RETRIEVE_USER_CONFIG_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="SALESFORCE_INBOX_TRANSPORT_CONNECTION_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="SALESFORCE_INBOX_TRANSPORT_TOKEN_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="SALESFORCE_INBOX_TRANSPORT_UNKNOWN_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_FLOW"/>
        <enumeration value="SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER"/>
        <enumeration value="SHARE_NEEDED_FOR_CHILD_OWNER"/>
        <enumeration value="SINGLE_EMAIL_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="SOCIAL_ACCOUNT_NOT_FOUND"/>
        <enumeration value="SOCIAL_ACTION_INVALID"/>
        <enumeration value="SOCIAL_PERSONA_NOT_FOUND"/>
        <enumeration value="SOCIAL_POST_INVALID"/>
        <enumeration value="SOCIAL_POST_NOT_FOUND"/>
        <enumeration value="STANDARD_PRICE_NOT_DEFINED"/>
        <enumeration value="STORAGE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="STRING_TOO_LONG"/>
        <enumeration value="SUBDOMAIN_IN_USE"/>
        <enumeration value="TABSET_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="TEMPLATE_NOT_ACTIVE"/>
        <enumeration value="TEMPLATE_NOT_FOUND"/>
        <enumeration value="TERMS_OF_SERVICE_UNREAD"/>
        <enumeration value="TERRITORY_REALIGN_IN_PROGRESS"/>
        <enumeration value="TEXT_DATA_OUTSIDE_SUPPORTED_CHARSET"/>
        <enumeration value="TOO_MANY_APEX_REQUESTS"/>
        <enumeration value="TOO_MANY_ENUM_VALUE"/>
        <enumeration value="TOO_MANY_POSSIBLE_USERS_EXIST"/>
        <enumeration value="TRANSFER_REQUIRES_READ"/>
        <enumeration value="UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW"/>
        <enumeration value="UNAVAILABLE_RECORDTYPE_EXCEPTION"/>
        <enumeration value="UNAVAILABLE_REF"/>
        <enumeration value="UNDELETE_FAILED"/>
        <enumeration value="UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION"/>
        <enumeration value="UNKNOWN_TOKEN_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="UNSAFE_HTML_CONTENT"/>
        <enumeration value="UNSPECIFIED_EMAIL_ADDRESS"/>
        <enumeration value="UNSUPPORTED_APEX_TRIGGER_OPERATON"/>
        <enumeration value="UNSUPPORTED_SOCIAL_PROVIDER"/>
        <enumeration value="UNVERIFIED_SENDER_ADDRESS"/>
        <enumeration value="UPDATE_GOOGLE_EMAIL_LABEL_FAILED"/>
        <enumeration value="USER_OWNS_PORTAL_ACCOUNT_EXCEPTION"/>
        <enumeration value="USER_WITH_APEX_SHARES_EXCEPTION"/>
        <enumeration value="VF_COMPILE_ERROR"/>
        <enumeration value="WEBLINK_SIZE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"/>
        <enumeration value="WEBLINK_URL_INVALID"/>
        <enumeration value="WRONG_CONTROLLER_TYPE"/>
        <enumeration value="XCLEAN_UNEXPECTED_ERROR"/>
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

Answer (score 2):

For a list of status codes defined in your instance, you can find them at:

```
https://[yourinstance].my.salesforce.com/services/wsdl/tooling
```

under the section

```
<xsd:simpleType name="StatusCode">
```

I have yet to find the messages which correspond to those codes, but still looking.

Comment: Is there a way to recognize custom error codes? Browsing our file i found no prefix or postfix that would indicate which errors are raised by our custom code. Is there a convention to mark custom error codes?