# Complete list of Standard Field Validation Error Messages

Tags: visualforce, validation, error-messages, custom-controller

This is specifically dealing with custom Visual Force controllers that do data validation and error checking prior to attempting to save records via a DML statement.  During our validations we will populate custom Field and Page error messages.  However, there are times when Salesforce will apply their own validation rules prior to our validation checks running.  This generally occurs on Email fields and Text Area fields when the user supplied data does not meet the field requirements.  Specifically, Salesforce will add a field error of "Error: Invalid Email Address." if the data entered does not include an "@" or a ".".  For Text Area, we are getting "Error: Cannot user more than 1,500 characters." if users paste in a response exceeding 1,500 characters.

We don't have a problem with this behavior, but we would like to standardize our Requirements Documents around Error Messages.  We are attempting to find a list of all of Salesforce's Standard field validation error messages so that we can incorporate them into our Requirements process.

Googling has yet to yield any meaningful answer.  I can't find it in the SOAP or APEX Developer guides.

Does anyone out there have a list of the Standard Error messages generated by Salesforce for field validation errors?

Comment: Related: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/98990

Answer (score 6):

The strings are version and language dependent. However, there is a way to find which codes are valid for a particular release: go into Setup > Develop > API, generate the Enterprise WSDL, and find the StatusCode simpleType. In version 39.0, in my org, it looks like the following values apply. The actual value that will be output depends on the user's language settings. You can use the getDmlType method to determine which type of error it was, regardless of the user's language settings.

---

```
ALL_OR_NONE_OPERATION_ROLLED_BACK
ALREADY_IN_PROCESS
APEX_DATA_ACCESS_RESTRICTION
ASSIGNEE_TYPE_REQUIRED
AURA_COMPILE_ERROR
BAD_CUSTOM_ENTITY_PARENT_DOMAIN
BCC_NOT_ALLOWED_IF_BCC_COMPLIANCE_ENABLED
CANNOT_CASCADE_PRODUCT_ACTIVE
CANNOT_CHANGE_FIELD_TYPE_OF_APEX_REFERENCED_FIELD
CANNOT_CHANGE_FIELD_TYPE_OF_REFERENCED_FIELD
CANNOT_CREATE_ANOTHER_MANAGED_PACKAGE
CANNOT_DEACTIVATE_DIVISION
CANNOT_DELETE_GLOBAL_ACTION_LIST
CANNOT_DELETE_LAST_DATED_CONVERSION_RATE
CANNOT_DELETE_MANAGED_OBJECT
CANNOT_DISABLE_LAST_ADMIN
CANNOT_ENABLE_IP_RESTRICT_REQUESTS
CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER
CANNOT_FREEZE_SELF
CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY
CANNOT_MODIFY_MANAGED_OBJECT
CANNOT_PASSWORD_LOCKOUT
CANNOT_POST_TO_ARCHIVED_GROUP
CANNOT_RENAME_APEX_REFERENCED_FIELD
CANNOT_RENAME_APEX_REFERENCED_OBJECT
CANNOT_RENAME_REFERENCED_FIELD
CANNOT_RENAME_REFERENCED_OBJECT
CANNOT_REPARENT_RECORD
CANNOT_UPDATE_CONVERTED_LEAD
CANT_DISABLE_CORP_CURRENCY
CANT_UNSET_CORP_CURRENCY
CHILD_SHARE_FAILS_PARENT
CIRCULAR_DEPENDENCY
CLEAN_SERVICE_ERROR
COLLISION_DETECTED
COMMUNITY_NOT_ACCESSIBLE
CONFLICTING_ENVIRONMENT_HUB_MEMBER
CONFLICTING_SSO_USER_MAPPING
CUSTOM_APEX_ERROR
CUSTOM_CLOB_FIELD_LIMIT_EXCEEDED
CUSTOM_ENTITY_OR_FIELD_LIMIT
CUSTOM_FIELD_INDEX_LIMIT_EXCEEDED
CUSTOM_INDEX_EXISTS
CUSTOM_LINK_LIMIT_EXCEEDED
CUSTOM_METADATA_LIMIT_EXCEEDED
CUSTOM_METADATA_REL_FIELD_MANAGEABILITY
CUSTOM_SETTINGS_LIMIT_EXCEEDED
CUSTOM_TAB_LIMIT_EXCEEDED
DATACLOUDADDRESS_NO_RECORDS_FOUND
DATACLOUDADDRESS_PROCESSING_ERROR
DATACLOUDADDRESS_SERVER_ERROR
DELETE_FAILED
DELETE_OPERATION_TOO_LARGE
DELETE_REQUIRED_ON_CASCADE
DEPENDENCY_EXISTS
DUPLICATES_DETECTED
DUPLICATE_CASE_SOLUTION
DUPLICATE_COMM_NICKNAME
DUPLICATE_CUSTOM_ENTITY_DEFINITION
DUPLICATE_CUSTOM_TAB_MOTIF
DUPLICATE_DEVELOPER_NAME
DUPLICATE_EXTERNAL_ID
DUPLICATE_MASTER_LABEL
DUPLICATE_SENDER_DISPLAY_NAME
DUPLICATE_USERNAME
DUPLICATE_VALUE
EMAIL_ADDRESS_BOUNCED
EMAIL_EXTERNAL_TRANSPORT_CONNECTION_ERROR
EMAIL_EXTERNAL_TRANSPORT_PERMISSION_ERROR
EMAIL_EXTERNAL_TRANSPORT_TOKEN_ERROR
EMAIL_EXTERNAL_TRANSPORT_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS_ERROR
EMAIL_EXTERNAL_TRANSPORT_UNKNOWN_ERROR
EMAIL_NOT_PROCESSED_DUE_TO_PRIOR_ERROR
EMAIL_OPTED_OUT
EMAIL_TEMPLATE_FORMULA_ERROR
EMAIL_TEMPLATE_MERGEFIELD_ACCESS_ERROR
EMAIL_TEMPLATE_MERGEFIELD_ERROR
EMAIL_TEMPLATE_MERGEFIELD_VALUE_ERROR
EMAIL_TEMPLATE_PROCESSING_ERROR
EMPTY_SCONTROL_FILE_NAME
ENTITY_FAILED_IFLASTMODIFIED_ON_UPDATE
ENTITY_IS_ARCHIVED
ENTITY_IS_DELETED
ENTITY_IS_LOCKED
ENTITY_SAVE_ERROR
ENTITY_SAVE_VALIDATION_ERROR
ENVIRONMENT_HUB_MEMBERSHIP_CONFLICT
ENVIRONMENT_HUB_MEMBERSHIP_ERROR_JOINING_HUB
ENVIRONMENT_HUB_MEMBERSHIP_USER_ALREADY_IN_HUB
ENVIRONMENT_HUB_MEMBERSHIP_USER_NOT_ORG_ADMIN
ERROR_IN_MAILER
EXCHANGE_WEB_SERVICES_URL_INVALID
FAILED_ACTIVATION
FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION
FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION
FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION
FIELD_KEYWORD_LIST_MATCH_LIMIT
FIELD_MAPPING_ERROR
FIELD_MODERATION_RULE_BLOCK
FIELD_NOT_UPDATABLE
FILE_EXTENSION_NOT_ALLOWED
FILE_SIZE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED
FILTERED_LOOKUP_LIMIT_EXCEEDED
FIND_DUPLICATES_ERROR
FUNCTIONALITY_NOT_ENABLED
HAS_PUBLIC_REFERENCES
HTML_FILE_UPLOAD_NOT_ALLOWED
IMAGE_TOO_LARGE
INACTIVE_OWNER_OR_USER
INACTIVE_RULE_ERROR
INSERT_UPDATE_DELETE_NOT_ALLOWED_DURING_MAINTENANCE
INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY
INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY
INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_TO_INSIGHTSEXTERNALDATA
INSUFFICIENT_CREDITS
INTERNAL_ERROR
INVALID_ACCESS_LEVEL
INVALID_ACCESS_TOKEN
INVALID_ARGUMENT_TYPE
INVALID_ASSIGNEE_TYPE
INVALID_ASSIGNMENT_RULE
INVALID_BATCH_OPERATION
INVALID_CONTENT_TYPE
INVALID_CREDIT_CARD_INFO
INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY
INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_TYPE_FOR_FIELD
INVALID_CURRENCY_CONV_RATE
INVALID_CURRENCY_CORP_RATE
INVALID_CURRENCY_ISO
INVALID_DATA_CATEGORY_GROUP_REFERENCE
INVALID_DATA_URI
INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS
INVALID_EMPTY_KEY_OWNER
INVALID_ENTITY_FOR_MATCH_ENGINE_ERROR
INVALID_ENTITY_FOR_MATCH_OPERATION_ERROR
INVALID_ENTITY_FOR_UPSERT
INVALID_ENVIRONMENT_HUB_MEMBER
INVALID_EVENT_DELIVERY
INVALID_EVENT_SUBSCRIPTION
INVALID_FIELD
INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE
INVALID_FIELD_WHEN_USING_TEMPLATE
INVALID_FILTER_ACTION
INVALID_GOOGLE_DOCS_URL
INVALID_ID_FIELD
INVALID_INET_ADDRESS
INVALID_INPUT
INVALID_LINEITEM_CLONE_STATE
INVALID_MARKUP
INVALID_MASTER_OR_TRANSLATED_SOLUTION
INVALID_MESSAGE_ID_REFERENCE
INVALID_NAMESPACE_PREFIX
INVALID_OAUTH_URL
INVALID_OPERATION
INVALID_OPERATOR
INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST
INVALID_OWNER
INVALID_PACKAGE_LICENSE
INVALID_PACKAGE_VERSION
INVALID_PARTNER_NETWORK_STATUS
INVALID_PERSON_ACCOUNT_OPERATION
INVALID_PROVIDER_TYPE
INVALID_QUERY_LOCATOR
INVALID_READ_ONLY_USER_DML
INVALID_REFRESH_TOKEN
INVALID_RUNTIME_VALUE
INVALID_SAVE_AS_ACTIVITY_FLAG
INVALID_SESSION_ID
INVALID_SETUP_OWNER
INVALID_SIGNUP_COUNTRY
INVALID_SIGNUP_OPTION
INVALID_SITE_DELETE_EXCEPTION
INVALID_SITE_FILE_IMPORTED_EXCEPTION
INVALID_SITE_FILE_TYPE_EXCEPTION
INVALID_STATUS
INVALID_SUBDOMAIN
INVALID_TYPE
INVALID_TYPE_FOR_OPERATION
INVALID_TYPE_ON_FIELD_IN_RECORD
INVALID_USERID
IP_RANGE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED
JIGSAW_IMPORT_LIMIT_EXCEEDED
LICENSE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED
LIGHT_PORTAL_USER_EXCEPTION
LIMIT_EXCEEDED
MALFORMED_ID
MANAGER_NOT_DEFINED
MASSMAIL_RETRY_LIMIT_EXCEEDED
MASS_MAIL_LIMIT_EXCEEDED
MATCH_DEFINITION_ERROR
MATCH_OPERATION_ERROR
MATCH_OPERATION_INVALID_ENGINE_ERROR
MATCH_OPERATION_INVALID_RULE_ERROR
MATCH_OPERATION_MISSING_ENGINE_ERROR
MATCH_OPERATION_MISSING_OBJECT_TYPE_ERROR
MATCH_OPERATION_MISSING_OPTIONS_ERROR
MATCH_OPERATION_MISSING_RULE_ERROR
MATCH_OPERATION_UNKNOWN_RULE_ERROR
MATCH_OPERATION_UNSUPPORTED_VERSION_ERROR
MATCH_PRECONDITION_FAILED
MATCH_RUNTIME_ERROR
MATCH_SERVICE_ERROR
MATCH_SERVICE_TIMED_OUT
MATCH_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE_ERROR
MAXIMUM_CCEMAILS_EXCEEDED
MAXIMUM_DASHBOARD_COMPONENTS_EXCEEDED
MAXIMUM_HIERARCHY_CHILDREN_REACHED
MAXIMUM_HIERARCHY_LEVELS_REACHED
MAXIMUM_HIERARCHY_TREE_SIZE_REACHED
MAXIMUM_SIZE_OF_ATTACHMENT
MAXIMUM_SIZE_OF_DOCUMENT
MAX_ACTIONS_PER_RULE_EXCEEDED
MAX_ACTIVE_RULES_EXCEEDED
MAX_APPROVAL_STEPS_EXCEEDED
MAX_DEPTH_IN_FLOW_EXECUTION
MAX_FORMULAS_PER_RULE_EXCEEDED
MAX_RULES_EXCEEDED
MAX_RULE_ENTRIES_EXCEEDED
MAX_TASK_DESCRIPTION_EXCEEEDED
MAX_TM_RULES_EXCEEDED
MAX_TM_RULE_ITEMS_EXCEEDED
MAX_TRIGGERS_EXCEEDED
MERGE_FAILED
METADATA_FIELD_UPDATE_ERROR
MISSING_ARGUMENT
MISSING_RECORD
MIXED_DML_OPERATION
NONUNIQUE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS
NO_ACCESS_TOKEN
NO_ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_REFRESH
NO_APPLICABLE_PROCESS
NO_ATTACHMENT_PERMISSION
NO_AUTH_PROVIDER
NO_INACTIVE_DIVISION_MEMBERS
NO_MASS_MAIL_PERMISSION
NO_PARTNER_PERMISSION
NO_REFRESH_TOKEN
NO_SUCH_USER_EXISTS
NO_TOKEN_ENDPOINT
NUMBER_OUTSIDE_VALID_RANGE
NUM_HISTORY_FIELDS_BY_SOBJECT_EXCEEDED
OPTED_OUT_OF_MASS_MAIL
OP_WITH_INVALID_USER_TYPE_EXCEPTION
PACKAGE_LICENSE_REQUIRED
PACKAGING_API_INSTALL_FAILED
PACKAGING_API_UNINSTALL_FAILED
PALI_INVALID_ACTION_ID
PALI_INVALID_ACTION_NAME
PALI_INVALID_ACTION_TYPE
PAL_INVALID_ASSISTANT_RECOMMENDATION_TYPE_ID
PAL_INVALID_ENTITY_ID
PAL_INVALID_FLEXIPAGE_ID
PAL_INVALID_LAYOUT_ID
PAL_INVALID_PARAMETERS
PA_API_EXCEPTION
PA_AXIS_FAULT
PA_INVALID_ID_EXCEPTION
PA_NO_ACCESS_EXCEPTION
PA_NO_DATA_FOUND_EXCEPTION
PA_URI_SYNTAX_EXCEPTION
PA_VISIBLE_ACTIONS_FILTER_ORDERING_EXCEPTION
PORTAL_NO_ACCESS
PORTAL_USER_ALREADY_EXISTS_FOR_CONTACT
PORTAL_USER_CREATION_RESTRICTED_WITH_ENCRYPTION
PRIVATE_CONTACT_ON_ASSET
PROCESSING_HALTED
QA_INVALID_CREATE_FEED_ITEM
QA_INVALID_SUCCESS_MESSAGE
QUERY_TIMEOUT
QUICK_ACTION_LIST_ITEM_NOT_ALLOWED
QUICK_ACTION_LIST_NOT_ALLOWED
RECORD_IN_USE_BY_WORKFLOW
REL_FIELD_BAD_ACCESSIBILITY
REPUTATION_MINIMUM_NUMBER_NOT_REACHED
REQUEST_RUNNING_TOO_LONG
REQUIRED_FEATURE_MISSING
REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING
RETRIEVE_EXCHANGE_ATTACHMENT_FAILED
RETRIEVE_EXCHANGE_EMAIL_FAILED
RETRIEVE_EXCHANGE_EVENT_FAILED
RETRIEVE_GOOGLE_EMAIL_FAILED
RETRIEVE_GOOGLE_EVENT_FAILED
SALESFORCE_INBOX_TRANSPORT_CONNECTION_ERROR
SALESFORCE_INBOX_TRANSPORT_TOKEN_ERROR
SALESFORCE_INBOX_TRANSPORT_UNKNOWN_ERROR
SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_FLOW
SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER
SHARE_NEEDED_FOR_CHILD_OWNER
SINGLE_EMAIL_LIMIT_EXCEEDED
SOCIAL_ACCOUNT_NOT_FOUND
SOCIAL_ACTION_INVALID
SOCIAL_POST_INVALID
SOCIAL_POST_NOT_FOUND
STANDARD_PRICE_NOT_DEFINED
STORAGE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED
STRING_TOO_LONG
SUBDOMAIN_IN_USE
TABSET_LIMIT_EXCEEDED
TEMPLATE_NOT_ACTIVE
TEMPLATE_NOT_FOUND
TERMS_OF_SERVICE_UNREAD
TERRITORY_REALIGN_IN_PROGRESS
TEXT_DATA_OUTSIDE_SUPPORTED_CHARSET
TOO_MANY_APEX_REQUESTS
TOO_MANY_ENUM_VALUE
TOO_MANY_POSSIBLE_USERS_EXIST
TRANSFER_REQUIRES_READ
UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW
UNAVAILABLE_RECORDTYPE_EXCEPTION
UNAVAILABLE_REF
UNDELETE_FAILED
UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION
UNKNOWN_TOKEN_ERROR
UNSAFE_HTML_CONTENT
UNSPECIFIED_EMAIL_ADDRESS
UNSUPPORTED_APEX_TRIGGER_OPERATON
UNVERIFIED_SENDER_ADDRESS
USER_OWNS_PORTAL_ACCOUNT_EXCEPTION
USER_WITH_APEX_SHARES_EXCEPTION
VF_COMPILE_ERROR
WEBLINK_SIZE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED
WEBLINK_URL_INVALID
WRONG_CONTROLLER_TYPE
XCLEAN_UNEXPECTED_ERROR
```

Comment: So this was helpful in getting further down the rabbit hole.  But how do I get from the Enum value in the StatusCode to the actual string populated on the page?  I looked into the getDmlType() method to find an answer, but I think it demonstrated that these are not the correct errors.  I created a contact, added a bogus email, tried to do an Insert and checked the message.  I got back the correct status code, but the DML message was "Email Address: invalid email address: test"  Also, we are getting these messages before we do a DML statement.  These are field level Error messages in VF pages.

Comment: @RobDavis I see what you mean now. I don't think there is a meaningful way to get those errors, as the strings have no master list, we don't have a convenient method for rendering these values. I think the best you can really do is simply document them as you run in to them. There's only like 10 or so that are incredibly common, the remainder you should rarely ever run in to.