# Can someone provide me the list of SOQL exceptions?

Tags: soql, governorlimits, dynamic-soql

Can someone provide me the list of SOQL exceptions? a URL link which has all the exceptions and explanations. Thanks in advance

Comment: Related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/98990

Answer (score 3):

The Enterprise WSDL generated in any organization lists the exceptions that the platform might throw at you. You can find it under Setup > Integrations > API. The file is pretty big, so one might want to save it and open in a text editor.

Search for the tag `simpleType` with the "name" parameter `ExceptionCode`.

---

As for the SOQL exceptions, you won't find any with "SOQL" in the name, but you get some when searching using "QUERY":

- ASYNC_QUERY_UNSUPPORTED_QUERY
- DATACLOUD_API_INVALID_QUERY_EXCEPTION
- ENTITY_NOT_QUERYABLE
- ILLEGAL_QUERY_PARAMETER_VALUE
- INVALID_QUERY_FILTER_OPERATOR
- INVALID_QUERY_LOCATOR
- INVALID_QUERY_SCOPE
- MALFORMED_QUERY
- QUERY_TIMEOUT
- QUERY_TOO_COMPLICATED